# Remove elements from bash array by element property

Tags: arrays, bash

In bash, if I have an array of file names which I retrieve from a file like this:

```
readarray files < $MY_DIR/my_file_list.cfg
```

How can i remove any elements in the array `files` which are say shorter than four characters long?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop about every element of your array and check its element length and remove element if necessary.

```
for ((i=0;i<=${#files[@]};i++)); do
  [[ ${#files[$i]} -lt 4 ]] && unset files[$i]
done

declare -p
```

---

> `${#files[@]}`: number of elements in array `files`
>
> `${#files[$i]}`: length of element `$i`
>
> `-lt`: arithmetic test less-than

Comment: Better to use arithmetic operator `((` instead of `[[` with `-lt`: `(( ${#i} < 4 ))`

Comment: @heemayl: This is also possible. I personally use `<` and `>` only with input and output redirection.

Comment: That's fine but `<`, `>` et al. goes well with the typical programming paradigm...

Answer (score 1):

Test code, using `bash` *substring expansion*:

```
printf "abc\nabcdefg\na\nabcd\n" | while read x ; do [ "${x:4}" ] && echo $x ; done
```

Output:

```
abcdefg
abcd
```

Therefore:

1. Pure `bash` code:

   ```
   readarray files < <(while read x ; do [ "${x:4}" ] && echo $x ; done < \
                          $MY_DIR/my_file_list.cfg )
   ```
2. Simpler `grep` aided code:

   ```
   readarray files < <(grep '^....' $MY_DIR/my_file_list.cfg)
   ```

---

These methods waste no array memory on too-short entries.  The worst case would be if *my_file_list.cfg* contained only one long name, but billions of short names.  (Billions of short names might exhaust `bash`'s memory, or at least lead to swapping, or thrashing.)

Comment: Passing data into `readarray` through a pipe will result in the array being created in the subshell and hence not available to the parent.  Use process substitution instead.

Comment: @agc: To make this possible, it is necessary to disable job control and enable bash‘s lastpipe feature: `set +m; shopt -s lastpipe; printf "abc\nabcdefg\na\nabcd\n" | readarray files; declare -p files`

Comment: @Cyrus, Thanks, it's good to know it's possible.  I wonder if either method, (i.e. your `lastpipe` tweak, or *codeforester*'s process substitution), has any run-time advantages over the other...